# Vim jump word forward and enter insert mode

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode

I'm using vim for python scripting and found that I pretty much often need to jump a word forward `e`-button and enter insert mode. Is there some built-in shortcut for this or `ea` is reuqired to push all the time?

Answer (score 6):

There's no single-key shortcut for this.

Two keystrokes is already pretty short, but there are a few keys on your keyboard that Vim doesn't already use in normal mode, or that carry out a command already provided by another key, so if you wanted to you could set up your own shortcut with something like:

```
nnoremap <space> ea
```

See `:h normal-index` for the complete list of keys that already have functions in normal mode. Anything that's *not* listed you can use, and anything that has the description "same as ..." would also be a good candidate. See also `:h map-which-keys` for some suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no better solution than pressing `ea`.

But you can always add your own shortcut (even on a single char if you want but you will override one default shortcut because everything is taken, choose something you don't use often).

```
nnoremap <F2> ea
```

for example.